# Manually adding file to classpath

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to test a war that I deployed in Tomcat 7, however it seems its missing a xml configuration:

**web.xml**

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>StorageEngine</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.jpeterson.littles3.StorageEngine</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:StorageEngine-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
```

I have downloaded the `StorageEngine-servlet.xml` separately, to be able to satisfy this `init-param` where do I need put the
xml file in the `\webapps\littleS3-2.3.0\WEB-INF` folder, just relative to the `web.xml`? Or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it belongs in WEB-INF/classes of your WAR file.   That is always in the CLASSPATH of a Tomcat app, loaded by the app class loader.

Answer (score 0):

Given the mapping it would need to be placed in the root of your classpath.  Try placing it within the root of any source folder